# Вывести изображение из sqlite android

Tags: java, android

Есть строка:

```
String img1=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("img"));
```

В ней хранится полученное значение из бд , но как его запихнуть в **ImageView**. **String** не поддерживает!

Пробовал в массив

```
imageint = new int[]{images};
```

images - это:

```
int images = c.getColumnIndex("img");
```

Но без **c.getString** выводит иероглифы а с **c.getString** массив не может быть тип Int parse.int бьет ошибку. Подскажите, как это реализовать?

Comment: А что вы получаете из базы по запросу? Ссылку на изображение?

Comment: `int img1 = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("img"));` не?

Comment: в каком виде хранятся изображения в базе?

Comment: в базе хранится R.drawable.aple , такого типа ссылка

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понял, вы в базе храните ссылку на изображение, строкой типа "R.drawable.name_of_image". А вам нужно преобразовать сие в идентификатор изображения, который имеет тип **int** и хранится в классе **R**. Если так, то вам нужно было гуглить по запросу

> [get resource id by name](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=get%20resource%20id%20by%20name)

или

> [get drawable by name](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=get%20drawable%20by%20name)

Так можно получить [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3476470/3212712):

```
int drawableResourceId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("nameOfDrawable", "drawable", context.getPackageName());
```

Т.е. в вашем случае:

```
int drawableResourceId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("aple", "drawable", context.getPackageName());
yoursImageView.setImageResource(drawableResourceId);
```